# Why is there a fixed partition backlog with the Spring-Kafka framework？

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

SpringBoot version is 2.3.7, Spring Kafka version is 2.7.2
Only one consumer group, subscribed to two topic respectively. A and B, A with 30 partitions, B has 3 partitions, concurrency = 8, max.poll.records = 50, Use the partition allocation policy of range, where partition 9 in A is fixed, no other partition is backlogged, and no partition B is backlogged. The production speed of each partition in A and B is balanced, and the data in partition B will be less. After increasing concurrency, all partitions will not be backlogged. But I would like to know why in this scenario, it is fixed to be 9 partitions instead of other partitions.

I tried to add log observation phenomenon in Spring-Kafka, 8,9,10,11 in A, 2 in B, these 5 partitions are consumed by a consumer subscription, where 8 and 11 are on the same broker and 10 is on a separate broker. 9 in A and 2 in B were on the same broker, and it was observed from the log that 9 in A pulled significantly less data than the other three partitions in A

Comment: The processing logic is the same for each consumer

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the question. Broker placement doesn't matter. Two topics are never related to each other for lag or consumer fetching... If something is "slow", then you typically have hardware related issues like network saturation, or high disk IO... The spring-kafka framework shouldn't be causing that either. Did you test with a standalone consumer?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I tried to look at the hardware performance of the machine deployment and did not find high network latency and high disk IO.

Comment: I tried to find the problem from the source code of the kafka client and found that each consumer maintained a HashSet of its own nodeIds. When a consumer sends a pull message request to the Kafka Server, it determines whether the requested nodeId is included in the collection, and if so, it does not initiate all requests for that node. When the consumer pulls partial partition data for topic A and Topic B, the requested nodeId is the same, resulting in slower partial partition consumption

Comment: Yes，I test with a standalone consumer

Comment: But what happens if the leader partition for  each topic are different nodes? By standalone I meant without Spring, since that's likely not the issue